# Massive difference in Data transfer between two Servers

Tags: sql-server, web-services, asp.net-web-api

We have a Web application which is running on MS SQL 2014 server. The application consists of the following

SQL 2014 + API Server + Web Server.

For testing purposes all of these are hosted on the same physical server.

The requests go from web server to the API server where the stored procedures pull data from the SQL server and then sent back to the Web Server in JASON/REST API format.

We have hosted this configuration on two different physical servers on a good hosting environments on tier 1 providers. So its the same code & DB on two physical servers, on in US one in Canada. We noticed significant User page load time difference between the two environments. The code, data is Identical.

When we analyzed the fiddler trace for each page, we noticed a large difference between data transfer between the two servers, here I am giving you a example of the difference in one of the API's

I am giving an example of time and data difference while execution one of the API's called “ GetPortfolioReportData”

Server 1  - Time 19350 (ms)  - Data 5.5 MB

Server 2  - Time 1260 (ms) - Data 233 KB

I am extremely confused on why this difference would occur on identical code and server environments? Is this some configuration issue on SQL Server or some compression needs to be enabled?

Can anyone give any points to the cause of this?

Appreciate your help

Regards,

Comment: It is very likely that only one of the servers has compression enabled. "On the Server Roles page, expand Web Server (IIS), expand Web Server, expand Performance, and then select Static Content Compression and/or Dynamic Content Compression. Click Next." - https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpcompression

Comment: Gzip compression is active on all the servers :(